# Implement Hyperlink with gwt places and activites

Tags: gwt

I want to understand how to use hyperlink in gwt places and activieties. I am not sure why eclipse is giving an error in this.

```
@UiField Hyperlink entInvoiceCompare;


public SimplePanel getCenterPanel () {
    return centerPanel;
}


entInvoiceCompare.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
         SmartEBRM.getClientFactory().getPlaceController().goTo(new EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace());
     }

});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if Hyperlink widgets work well with Activities and Places.

Use a Label instead. You can style it to look like a button or a link in your CSS.

Comment: Thanks. Can I use a button instead and make it look like a Hyperlink?

Comment: If you want it to look like a link, use a Label - it's easier to style than a Button (browsers apply several default styles to Button elements).